# Sorgenfrey line is not orderable

Tags: general-topology, sorgenfrey-line

How can I prove that the [Sorgenfrey line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) is not a [linearly ordered topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology), i.e., that the Sorgenfrey topology on $\mathbb R$ is not the order topology for some linear ordering?

I tried to prove this by using compactness or unconnectness...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Sorgenfrey line is not linearly orderable](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15201/conversation/sorgenfrey-line-is-not-linearly-orderable) Notice that there are also some references given there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual argument is as follows: Lutzer showed in 1969 ([in this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1969-022-02/S0002-9939-1969-0248761-1/S0002-9939-1969-0248761-1.pdf)) that an orderable space $X$ is metrisable iff it has a $G_\delta$ diagonal (i.e. the set $\Delta_X = \{(x,x) : x \in X\}$ is a countable intersection of open sets in $X \times X$ in the product topology).

And the Sorgenfrey line has a $G_\delta$ diagonal but is not metrisable, so cannot be orderable.

Comment: How can i find a simple proof for this theorem?

Comment: I added a link to the original paper. It does need other proofs again etc. I know of no good book that covers all this in detail.

Comment: Thank you!you helped me alot.